# SQL Select column tinyint

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a column:

```
txntype (tinyint, not null)
```

I'm doing a select where value of txntype is equal to 9:

```
where CAST(txntype as varchar(3)) = '9'
```

but is throwing an error:

> Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char.

I also tried:

```
where ISNUMERIC(txntype) = 9
```

but no records are selected when query is executed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you converting `tinyint` to text?

Comment: I tried standard txntype = 9 but throws an error "operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with tinyint"

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Can you try using `TINYINT(4)`?

Comment: SQL Server 2008.  It's from my clients server.  It's old. :)

Comment: Why on Earth did you tag with MySQL?

Comment: The error message indicates that the column's data type is not `tinyint` as you think, it's actually `uniqueidenfier`. Either you are looking at the wrong column or something very strange is happening here.

Comment: Are you maybe querying another database (db name in the drop-down) than the one you looked at in Object-Explorer in SSMS? I'd bet your table definitions are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the create statement of that table and the entire select statement, because it seems that either the column has been declared as a uniqueidentifier column or your select is doing something with the value of another column than the one you are using in your where clause.

Also, the [ISNUMERIC() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) returns a bit (0 or 1) indicating if a value can actually be converted to a numeric datatype. Comparing it with the value 9 will always yield "false" for that piece of the where clause.

If the column is actually a numeric type, you don't have to cast the value in the where clause either way.

```
    where [txntype] = 9
```

That is enough if the column is really a tinyint. And that's also the reason you need to be looking at other parts of the query in order to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `cast` or `isnumeric`

Just simply `txntype = 9`

Comment: I tried but throws an error "operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with tinyint"

Comment: What is your whole query ?

Comment: Try change where CAST(txntype as varchar(3)) = '9' to where CAST(txntype as varchar(36)) = '9'

Comment: @starko txntype is defined as a tinyint column: there is no way, it can contain more than 3 "characters", let alone allow non-numeric values being entered. The problem is not the column, but a comparison in the query that is causing this error.